# Was the frequency of mutations more during primitive earth due to radioactivity?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dna

Primitive earth was more radioactive (or was it really?) according to radiometric analysis of C14 which suddenly appeared at 4250 million years in the Hadeon eon. Is it possible that ancient high levels of radioactivity could affect the mutation rate of early organisms? Does mutation frequency accelerate evolutionary process and/or speciation?

Comment: Can you give a reference to the "higher $^{14}{C}$ radioactivity" assertion? It sounds *a priori* unlikely, given that the cosmic ray processes making carbon-14 from nitrogen would surely have operated equally at that time. Moreover, since the half-life of carbon-14 is about 5700 years, I can't see how any of it can have survived from a time almost a million half-lives ago. A reference could make everything clear.